# Android call back handler not being called

Tags: java, android, callback, android-handler

I'm using callback handler for parsing the response from webservice but it is not being called.

```
private static final int JSON_PARSE = 0;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
        switch (message.arg1) {
            case JSON_PARSE:
                String json = (String) message.obj;
                try {
                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

                    if (!jsonObj.toString().trim().isEmpty() && jsonObj != null) {

                     //Some code 

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

And I'm calling it like this

```
Message msgResponse = new Message();
msgResponse.obj = response;
msgResponse.arg1 = JSON_PARSE;
mHandler.handleMessage(msgResponse);
```

Comment: first: use `Message#obtain`, second: call `Message#sendToTarget`, for example: `Message.obtain(mHandler, JSON_PARSE, response).sendToTarget()`, note that you should `switch (message.what)`

Answer (score 0):

You should send message to handler as below

```
Message msgResponse = new Message();
msgResponse.obj = response;
msgResponse.arg1 = JSON_PARSE;
mHandler.sendMessage(msgResponse);
```